# VSTS NuGet Tool Installer Fails - ERR:unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: continuous-integration, nuget, azure-devops, devops, build-agent

I've configured a private build agent to use with VSTS.

I installed MSBuild tools and installed the agent as a service. Now I'm trying to build a MVC 5 project with it. The build fails in the **Use Nuget 4.3.0** task. After queueing a new build with diagnostics, here are the last lines:

```
2018-04-04T18:58:46.7604184Z ##[debug]checking cache: C:\agent\_work\_tool\NuGet\4.3.0\x64
2018-04-04T18:58:46.7609109Z ##[debug]not found
2018-04-04T18:58:46.7613274Z ##[debug]Agent.Version=2.131.0
2018-04-04T18:58:46.7614366Z ##[debug]Agent.ToolsDirectory=C:\agent\_work\_tool
2018-04-04T18:58:46.7619860Z ##[debug]evaluating 0 versions
2018-04-04T18:58:46.7621212Z ##[debug]match not found
2018-04-04T18:58:46.7628225Z ##[debug]Querying versions list
2018-04-04T18:58:46.8585728Z ERR:unable to verify the first certificate
2018-04-04T18:58:46.8587980Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
```

So I get this message: *unable to verify the first certificate*.

My first thought was the firewall blocking the **nuget.exe download**, but if I connect to the server, I can manually download it from this link (I believe the task tries to download from here):

https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v4.3.0/nuget.exe

How to fix this problem?

Comment: You can try to change that agent service account and try again. (Open services app> Double click agent service > Change log on account to your account > Restart service.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT thanks for your suggestion, I tried that with my user (since I have full access), however it didn't work.

Comment: Could you check if you can still reproduce this issue?

Comment: Hi @EddieChen-MSFT. I've just tested, and this error still occurs.

Comment: Did you have proxy configured for the agent? Can you share the entire logs for the task?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the nuget.exe tool manually, then add it to the environment variable, simple steps:

1. Download NuGet.exe tool to that agent machine manually (e.g. `d:\tool\nuget.exe`)
2. Open System Properties window > Advance > Environment variables
3. In System variables section, click New button > Variable name: `nuget`; Variable value: `d:\tool` > Click Ok
4. Select Path variable > Edit > add/append `%nuget%` item (the result will be `xxxx;%nuget%`)
5. Restart your machine

After that you can remove NuGet Tool Installer task from build definition.

Comment: After doing these steps, the build task could restore packages from NuGet and build the project, however the **Test Assemblies** task failed because it couldn't find Visual Studio 2015 (even though I installed VS Build Tools 2017). Then I added the **VsTest Platform Installer** before it, and it worked. The strange thing is the VsTest Platform Installer was able to download stuff, but the **Use NuGet task** wasn't, so I believe it's not a problem with the private server network.

Comment: You may open a new issue on [vsts-task github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues) for vsts task issue.